# Explanation of how to really square a circle in non-Euclidean space.

Tags: geometry

Whilst the Zeitgeist is that a circle cannot be squared, it appears that it actually can.  I ran across:-

> "While the circle cannot be squared in Euclidean space, it can in Gauss-Bolyai-Lobachevsky Space (Gray 1989)"

on the Wolfram website, [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircleSquaring.html).  I'm not a mathematician, so the challenge is to try and explain this simply. If it's at all possible to a lay person. I haven't pursued Gray's paper for that reason...

Comment: [this paper](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1052&context=rhumj) seems to be fairly easy to read.

Comment: or [this one](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF03024895#page-1)

Comment: @lulu I put a pdf here: http://zakuski.utsa.edu/~jagy/papers/Intelligencer_1995.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy  Thanks!

Comment: The classical problem of squaring the circle, which is a problem in Euclidean space, is impossible. If you change the space, you change the problem. You seem to be misinterpreting the result in a similar way to vos Savant, as Will writes in the first paragraph of his abstract.

Comment: This is not true exactly even in the hyperbolic space:"*Construction  of  a regular,  hyperbolic  quadrilateral  and  a  hyperbolic circle  of  the same area must be done separately. That is, neither object may be constructed directly from the other*", see [Squaring The Circle In The Hyperbolic Disk by Davis](https://scholar.rose-hulman.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=https://www.google.com/&httpsredir=1&article=1052&context=rhumj). This is similar to Euclidean trisection: one can construct 2 angles one of which is 1/3 of the other, but given *some* angle one can not trisect it in general.